# NameError: name 'anon_session_score' is not defined in django 1.10

Tags: python, django, django-views

Help please.
this is `model.py`

```
from django.db import models
import re

from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager
# Create your models here.

class Subject(models.Model):
    subject=models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True, blank=False)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Предмет"
        verbose_name_plural = "Предметы"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=False)
    url=models.SlugField(max_length=120,blank=False)
    subject=models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    random_order = models.BooleanField(blank=False,default=False)
    answers_at_end = models.BooleanField(blank=False,default=False)

    def save(self,force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args,**kwargs):
        self.url = re.sub(r'\s+','-',self.url).lower()

        self.url=''.join(letter for letter in self.url if letter.isalnum() or letter=='-')
        super(Quiz,self).save(force_insert,force_update,*args,**kwargs)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Тест"
        verbose_name_plural="Тесты"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all().select_subclasses()

    def anon_score_id(self):
        return str(self.id)+"_score"

    def anon_q_list(self):
        return str(self.id)+"_q_list"
    def anon_q_data(self):
        return str(self.id)+"_data"



class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz,verbose_name=u"Тест",blank=True)

    figure = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True,null=True)
    content=models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=False)
    random_order=models.BooleanField(blank=False,default=False)
    objects=InheritanceManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Вопрос"
        verbose_name_plural="Вопросы"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    def get_score(self,guess):#сюда надо положить все выбранные варианты пользоватля
        all_answers=Answer.objects.filter(question=self)
        rights=0
        for q_answer in all_answers:
            if q_answer.correct is True:
                rights+=1
        corrects=0
        incorrects=0
        for guess_id in guess:
            answer = Answer.objects.get(id=guess_id)
            if answer.correct is True:
                corrects+=1
            else:
                incorrects+=1

        if (rights==corrects)and(incorrects==0):
            return 2
        elif (rights%corrects==1)and(incorrects==1):
            return 1
        elif (rights%corrects>1)and(incorrects>1):
            return 0





    def random_answers(self,queryset):
        if self.random_order is True:
            return queryset.order_by('?')
        else:
            return queryset.order_by()
    def get_answers(self):
        return self.random_answers(Answer.objects.filter(question=self))
    def get_answers_list(self):
        return [(answer.id,answer.answer)for answer in 
        self.random_answers(Answer.objects.filter(question=self))]
    def answer_choice_to_string(self, guess):
        return Answer.objects.get(id=guess).answer




class Answer(models.Model):
    question=models.ForeignKey(Question, verbose_name="Вопрос")
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=False)
    correct=models.BooleanField(blank=False,default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Ответ"
        verbose_name_plural="Ответы"
```

and this is `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import *
from .forms import QuestionForm
from .models import *
import random

class QuizListView(ListView):
    model=Quiz

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset=super(QuizListView,self).get_queryset()
        return queryset

class QuizDetailView(DetailView):
    model=Quiz
    slug_field='url'

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object=self.get_object()

        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

class QuizTake(FormView):
    form_class=QuestionForm
    template_name='question.html'

    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.quiz=get_object_or_404(Quiz,url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])
        self.sitting = self.anon_load_sitting()
        if self.sitting is False:
            return render(request,'single_complete.html')
        return super(QuizTake,self).dispatch(request,*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, form_class=QuestionForm):
        self.question=self.anon_next_question()
        self.progress=self.anon_sitting_progress()


        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs=super(QuizTake,self).get_form_kwargs()

        return dict(kwargs,question=self.question)
    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.form_valid_anon(form)
        if not self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]:
            return self.final_result_anon()
        self.request.POST={}
        return super(QuizTake,self).get(self,self.request)

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context=super(QuizTake,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['question']=self.question
        context['quiz']=self.quiz
        if hasattr(self,'previous'):
            context['previous']=self.previous
        if hasattr(self,'progress'):
            context['progress']=self.progress
        return context

    def anon_load_sitting(self):
        if self.quiz.anon_q_list() in self.request.session:
            return self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]
        else:
            return self.new_anon_quiz_session()

    def new_anon_quiz_session(self):
        self.request.session.set_expiry(259200)
        questions = self.quiz.get_questions()
        question_list=[question.id for question in questions]
        if self.quiz.random_order is True:
            random.shuffle(question_list)

        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_score_id()]=0
        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]=question_list
        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]=dict(
            incorrect_questions=[],
            order=question_list,
            )
        return self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]

    def anon_next_question(self):
        next_question_id = self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()][0]
        return Question.objects.get_subclass(id=next_question_id)

    def anon_sitting_progress(self):
        total=len(self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['order'])
        answered = total - len(self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()])
        return (answered,total)

    def form_valid_anon(self,form):
        guess = form.cleaned_data['answers']
        score_to = self.question.get_score(guess)
        #добавить очки
        if score_to==2:
            self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_score_id()]+=1
        else:
            self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['incorrect_questions'].append(self.question.id)

        anon_session_score(self.request.session, score_to,2)

        self.previous={}
        if self.quiz.answers_at_end is not True:
            self.previous={
                'previous_answers':guess,
                'previous_outcome':score_to,
                'previous_question':self.question,
                'answers':self.question.get_answers(),
                'question_type':{self.question.__class__.__name__:True}
            }
        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]=self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()][1:]

    def final_result_anon(self):
        score = self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_score_id()]
        q_order = self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['order']
        session, session_possible = anon_session_score(self.request.session)
        if score is 0:
            score = "0"
        results={
            'score':score,
            'session':session,
            'possible':session_possible
        }

        del self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]

        if self.quiz.answers_at_end:
            results['questions']=sorted(
                self.quiz.question_set.filter(id__in=q_order).select_subclasses(),
                key=lambda q: q_order.index(q.id)
                )
            results['incorrect_questions']=(
                self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['incorrect_questions']
                )
        else:
            results['previous']=self.previous
        del self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]

        return render(self.request,'result.html',results)

    def anon_session_score(session,to_add=0, possible=0):
        if "session_score" not in session:
            session["session_score"],session["session_score_possible"] = 0,0
        if possible>0:
            session["session_score"]+=to_add
            session["session_score_possible"]+=possible

        return session["session_score"], session["session_score_possible"]
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/matem13/take/

Django Version: 1.10.3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'voud_quiz']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\virt_voud\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\virt_voud\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\virt_voud\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\virt_voud\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\virt_voud\src\voud_quiz\views.py" in dispatch
  35.       return super(QuizTake,self).dispatch(request,*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\virt_voud\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\virt_voud\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "D:\virt_voud\src\voud_quiz\views.py" in form_valid
  49.       self.form_valid_anon(form)

File "D:\virt_voud\src\voud_quiz\views.py" in form_valid_anon
  104.      anon_session_score(self.request.session, score_to,2)

Exception Type: NameError at /matem13/take/
Exception Value: name 'anon_session_score' is not defined
```

I don't understand why the view doesn't see the function `anon_session_score`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`anon_session_score` is a class method (i.e. it's a method that belongs to the view), so you must access it with `self.anon_session_score`.

Also, for the same reason, it should have `self` as its first parameter like all other methods in your view.

```
def anon_session_score(self, session, to_add=0, possible=0):
```